# Pandas, loop through each row of a column and append string to next column previous row

Tags: python, pandas

I've done this task through Excel, but it has taken a hell of a long time to run across the 300,000 rows of data so I was hoping I could get it done a lot faster using python.

What I have is like the following data frame,

```
               PartID   Notes   
0                 1       Fiv  
1                 2       Six  
2                 3       Pot  
3                 4       Lep  
4           Date is       New
```

The issue is I have been given a file where PartID has strings in it so index 4 has 'Date is' which should be in the Notes section. In Excel, what I did was use the value function to change everything to values so that the numbers became values while text were changed to be empty. I then used a macro to say if the row below is empty, then append the data to the Notes column in the row above and the output would look like below

```
               PartID  Notes      
0                 1      Fiv     
1                 2      Six     
2                 3      Pot     
3                 4 Lep Date is  
4                 5      New
```

Is there a way to do the same thing in Python using pandas?

Thanks!

Comment: how are you adding New in your output df

Comment: Sorry, I'm not adding it, I'm just saying that's the way I want it to work so append 'Date is' to 'Lep' in notes in index 3 such that index 4 gets replaced with the data below (i.e. the row below is already PartID 5 and Notes = New

Comment: you want to replace `Date is`  with the next number in the output df ?

Comment: is this solution  working
?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need, [pd.to_numeric](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) and [pd.Series.shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html)

```
a=df['PartID'].shift(-1).fillna('')

b=df['Notes']+a.loc[pd.to_numeric(a,errors='coerce').isnull()]

df['Notes']=b.combine_first(df['Notes'])

df['PartID']=np.arange(1,len(df['Notes'])+1)
print(df)
PartID  Notes      
    1      Fiv     
    2      Six     
    3      Pot     
    4     Lep Date is  
    5      New
```